# Lisp get element from a list

Tags: list, lisp

I'm tryng to get element from n position to m position. But I get some error.
How can I fix?

```
(defun element (list start end) 
 (dotimes (start  end) (n-esimo list start)
))

(defun n-esimo (l n)
  (cond ((equal n 0) (first l))
        (t (n-esimo (rest l) (- n 1)))))
```

Comment: Get NIL. No error but only nil and my list is not empty

Comment: `N-esimo` already exists in the Common Lisp standard, where it is called `nth` (although it takes the parameters the other way around).  `Dotimes` does not do what you think it does.  Look it up in the Hyperspec, e.g. by googling "clhs dotimes".

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to write it (unless your task is part of your homework, which you should then tell us by adding the tag `homework` to your question, or for other educational purposes.). Common Lisp has this function built-in. It is called [SUBSEQ](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_subseq.htm).